# How to extract unique elements from a list of classes in Scala

Tags: scala, cartesian-product

I have a list of case classes and the instances are the same or similar each other. I need to filter out this list from the "duplicates". In Scala, is there anything like this (pseudo code):

```
myList.unique ((obj1,obj2) => verifySimilitude(obj1,obj2))

def verifySimilitude(obj1:Foo, obj2:Foo):Boolean = // some logic to verify that objects are the same or at least similar
```

?

It is pretty much a "cartesian" product so I am wondering what it could be a good solution (keeping the code simple) to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such built-in function, but it's easy to create your own. For the sake of the example, I'm assuming `Foo` is simple `String` and `verifySimilitude` compares first characters of two strings.

```
type Foo = String

def verifySimilitude(obj1: Foo, obj2: Foo): Boolean = obj1.headOption == obj2.headOption

val myList = List("aa", "bb", "cc", "a", "b", "c", "d")

myList.foldLeft(List[String]()) {
  case (accum, el) => if (accum.exists(verifySimilitude(el, _))) accum else el :: accum
}.reverse
```

Result:

```
res0: List[String] = List(aa, bb, cc, d)
```

---

Alternative (more efficient) solution would be to create wrapper class that implements `equals` and `hashCode` according to your `verifySimilitude` behavior. Reusing the example above, this will look like:

```
class SimWrapper(val v:String) {
  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
    case that: SimWrapper => that.v.headOption == v.headOption
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode(): Int = v.headOption.hashCode()
}

myList.map(new SimWrapper(_)).distinct.map(_.v)
```

With the same result:

```
res1: List[String] = List(aa, bb, cc, d)
```

Second approach is more efficient (O(N) comparing to O(N<sup>2</sup>)), but it also has limited applications, as it makes sense only when you can define reasonably uniform `hashCode` for particular `verifySimilitude`.

Comment: thanks! very interesting solutions - I like the hash code one, although as you said, it might be tricky.